# Add a Flow button in a SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, json-formatting, power-automate, column-formatting

I have recently added a Flow button in a SharePoint Library. I found the code on internet (I have no experience in JSON).

I would like the button to be visible if:

1. Document status (choice column) is different than Approved
2. Approvers (person column) is not empty
3. Ready for Approval (boolean column) is True

I could implement only one condition: *Document status (choice column) is different than Approved*

But I wonder how can I add the other 2 conditions?

Any help would more than appreciated.

The code looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "span",
  "style": {
    "color": "#001f00"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "button",
      "style": {
        "border": "light",
        "background-color": "Orange",
        "color": "#001f00",
        "cursor": "pointer",
        "visibility": {
          "operator": "?",
          "operands": [
            {
              "operator": "!=",
              "operands": [
                "[$Document_x0020_status]",
                "Approved",
              ]
            },
            "visible",
            "hidden"
          ]
        }
      },
      "txtContent": "Send to Approval",
      "customRowAction": {
        "action": "executeFlow",
        "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"53c665d0-ce12-4148-aa5a-c7202557ea78\"}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Is "Approvers" column is single selection or multiple selection column?

Comment: is a multiple selection column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "span",
    "style": {
        "color": "#001f00"
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "button",
            "style": {
                "border": "light",
                "background-color": "Orange",
                "color": "#001f00",
                "cursor": "pointer",
                "display": "=if([$Document_x0020_status]!='Approved' && [$Approvers] && [$Ready for Approval],'block','none')"
            },
            "txtContent": "Send to Approval",
            "customRowAction": {
                "action": "executeFlow",
                "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"53c665d0-ce12-4148-aa5a-c7202557ea78\"}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note**: You need to use the **internal name** of your columns in JSON. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: Hi @claudia, have you tried this? is it working for you?

Comment: Thank you Ganesh! I have tried it, but it did not work. I have modifiied this part: "display": "=if([$Document_x0020_status]!='Approved' && [$Approvers]!=’’ && [$Ready_x0020_for_x0020_Approval]!=’Yes’,'block','none')"

Comment: Is it working now? or you are still facing some issues?

Comment: no it is not working

Comment: If your "Ready for Approval" column is of type boolean(Yes/No) then you need to check it like `[$Ready for Approval]==false` if you want to show the button if Ready for Approval is "No".

Comment: As per the description in your question, if you need to show the button if Ready for Approval is equal to "Yes" then you need to check its value using: `[$Ready for Approval]==true`. (Using correct internal names of your columns).

Comment: Hi Ganesh. Now is working. Thank you very much fro your help. This is the condition now:  "display": "=if([$Document_x0020_status]!='Approved' && [$Approvers]!='' && [$Ready_x0020_for_x0020_Approval]!=false,'block','none')"

Comment: Great. glad it helped you. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.